# MAC os terminal shell not working properly with open command

Tags: macos, shell, unix

Does anyone know what's going on when I open up the new shell in MAC?

[image: New shell window]

I checked my `~/.bash_profile`, and I don't think there's problem.

[image: bash_profile]

Also, I set a alias of chrome="open -a 'Google Chrome'" for my project, but when I try to do the command, chrome index.html, under my project directory in terminal, it's just google's new page that pops up instead of my project page. I tested with other command such as open index.html, it works opening up Safari. But I need google Chrome page for my project.

Comment: This is not a programming question. You will have better luck deleting this and asking on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ (cause OSX is UNIX).

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: Ehh... Sorry. I wouldn't do it again

Comment: I wouldn't do it now either. Why can't you copy that and put  the text in? Your question is up for closure because of it.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the closing quote (`'`) on line 7:

```
alias ls='ls -G'
# was missing -^
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Good catch. But why do I only get a new page instead of my project page when I do chrome command?